# Error connecting to Data Source in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, connection-string, datasource, ssrs-2008-r2, credentials

I am trying to connect to Datasource but getting this error:

```
An error occurred during local report processing. 
An error has occurred during report processing. 
Cannot create a connection to data source 'PO'.
You have specified integrated security or credentials in the connection string for the data source, but the data source is configured to use a different credential type. To use the values in the connection string, you must configure the unattended report processing account for the report server.
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks
Aruna

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like it forgot your password,
If it is an embedded data source > Right click on the Data source then go to properties > credentials.

If it is a shared data source go to the shared data sources, right click on the shared data source and hit Open, once in there click on credentials and enter the credentials again.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this issue occurred in Visual Studio when you connected to data source but were not able to create a report using that data source. What credential did you use when creating database. Windows authentication or username and password. Right click on data source in VS and select credential as same as your server/db in properties. Mine is windows auth for my server/db and selected the same for data source. so now I am able to create reports.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. For me, the problem was that I was using a DNS alias as the server name in the connection string. Once I changed that to the actual machine name my connection was solid.